# What is the proper procedure for offering a patch to the Python documentation?

Tags: python

I'm about to dive into the source code for the cgi.py module again because the MiniFieldStorage class is mentioned in the documentation, but not actually documented.  It occurred to me that I have done this so many times that maybe I could write documentation for it.  If I did, how should I submit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest posting an issue to the [documentation bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue?%40search_text=&title=&%40columns=title&id=&%40columns=id&stage=&creation=&creator=&activity=&%40columns=activity&%40sort=activity&actor=&nosy=&type=&components=4&versions=&dependencies=&assignee=&keywords=&priority=&%40columns=priority&%40group=priority&status=1&resolution=&nosy_count=&message_count=&%40pagesize=50&%40startwith=0&%40queryname=&%40old-queryname=&%40action=search), including the patch of course. This is mentioned in the section on [contributing](http://www.python.org/dev/contributing/) on the site.

If that doesn't work, or seems slow, I guess you can dig up developers to bug directly, but that can also be considered impolite, so read up first on the proper etiquette.

Answer (score 4):

There's a page regarding [Documentation Development](http://python.org/dev/doc/) on the official web site which looks like a good starting point. It appears as though you simply add to the issue tracker and attach a patch in the normal way.

In particular, it points to *[Documenting Python](http://docs.python.org/documenting/)*, which appears to be a rather exhaustive guide on formatting documentation; style guidelines, etc.